# service method does not recognize variable defined outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

Here is a service:

```
angular.module('core').factory('ServerErrorAlert', ['toaster',
    function(toaster) {
        return function(errorResponse) {
            toaster.pop('error', 'Error', errorResponse);
            if (deferred) {
                deferred.reject(errorResponse);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Here is how I call it :

```
function update(updatedTransaction, originalTransaction, updateLocal) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            updatedTransaction.$update(function() {
                if (updateLocal) {angular.extend(originalTransaction, updatedTransaction);}
                deferred.resolve(updateLocal ? originalTransaction : false);
            } , ServerErrorAlert);
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

The second update function that is calling ServerErrorAlert is also a service. I would like for it to return a promise so that it can be chained.

As you can see ServerErrorAlert is merely a convenience function. I do not define deferred in the service, instead I was hoping that it would recognize it. However, this is not the case, deferred is not recognized by the service.

I guess I am just confused because if I replace the ServerErrorAlert argument in $update with the return value of the service, namely the function definition, I am confident that it would recognize deferred. Why does it not recognize it once the method is extracted?

Basically, I want ServerErrorAlert to handle all server errors arising from $resource calls but I do not want to keep copy and pasting the function definition as the error callback. Instead I was hoping to just paste one word in there (for code reuse).

How can I accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Here is how I call it` ..where? No context shown.

Comment: `deferred` is simply not in the scope of the factory function. Instead, return `$q.reject(errorResponse)`

Comment: @charlietfl Hi charlietfl, $update is an asynchronous http request that takes a error callback as its second parameter. Here, I am passing ServerErrorAlert as the second parameter thus causing it to be called after an error response is received from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return a rejected promise, eg

```
.factory('ServerErrorAlert', ['$q', 'toaster', function($q, toaster) {
    return function(errorResponse) {
        toaster.pop('error', 'Error', errorResponse);
        return $q.reject(errorResponse);
    }
}]);
```

---

I would also change the way you're resolving the resource promise. You don't really need to create your own deferred object. Try this instead...

```
return updatedTransaction.$update().then(function() {
    if (updateLocal) { // assuming this is actually defined and in scope
        angular.extend(originalTransaction, updatedTransaction);
        return originalTransaction;
    }
    return false;
}, ServerErrorAlert);
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't post all of the code, my mistake. Can you take a look at the original post. I edited it with all of the code (where the service is called). I need to define deferred out there.

Comment: @pQuestions123 I already assumed you had that and covered it in my answer.

Comment: Hi Phil, sorry I didn't have time to really look over your answer until now. I guess I was not really clear enough. I am not sure if you are familiar with $update but it is part of the angular-resource module and is an http request. This second calling function is actually itself a service which I would like to return a promise as well. This way a controller calling the second service can call service.then

Comment: I guess I don't understand the first part of your answer. What do I gain by returning a new rejection from the ServerErrorAlert? It has no asynchronous call.... All I was trying to do was reject the first promise (which was returned by the first service which does have an asynchronous call).

Comment: @pQuestions123 I'm very familiar with `$resource`. The non-GET instance methods like `$update` return a promise so there's no need to create a new deferred object (as I mentioned in my answer). Returning a new rejection in `ServerErrorAlert` is the same as calling `deferred.reject` if `deferred` was in scope.

Comment: Hi Phil, I really appreciate you responses. I was hoping you could expand a little on the return statements. Are you saying that when the success call back returns a value that $update.$promise is resolved at that point to the value that the $update returns? Is the case the same when ServerErrorAlert returns $q.reject()? $update.$promise is rejected as well? Why is this? Thanks